# Consume JSON string with JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

Due to [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), a string can be a valid JSON document:

```
JSON-text = ws value ws
...
value = false / null / true / object / array / number / string
...
string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
```

Thus, a valid JSON can be `"Hello World"`.

Is it possible consume such a a JSON string with JAX-RS?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 16):

JAX-RS has a `@Consumes` annotation to specify the MIME media types of representations a resource can consume that were sent by the client.

Following is an example to accept a request with a `application/json` media type:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response bar(InputStream entity) {
        return Response.ok.build();
    }

}
```

If you send a request with a header of `Content-Type: application/json`, a response with a `200 OK` status will return to you. But if you send a request with a header of `Content-Type: application/xml`, a response with `406 Not Acceptable` will return. It is because `@Consumes` specify that request with JSON is acceptable but not others.

You can observe that `@Consumes` is noting about how to parse a request entity, but specify what media type should be accepted.

You can see that the above example has a parameter of `InputStream entity`. It is in fact the request entity. You can parse in the resource method of `bar` with a JSON parser library, e.g. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response bar(InputStream entity) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.readValue(inputStream, String.class);
    System.out.println(json);
    return Response.ok.build();
}
```

If you send a request with a body of "Hello World", you will see "Hello World" in your console. This is because `Jackson` know how to parse a JSON document specified in RFC 7159, but not JAX-RS.

In fact, JAX-RS implementation like RESTEasy already have JSON support with popular JSON parser library. Therefore you can simply create a resource method as follows:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response bar(String json) {
    System.out.println(json);
    return Response.ok.build();
}
```

You should get the same result.

Behind the scenes, JAX-RS has [MessageBodyReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) to convert HTTP request body to Java object. It is the class provide mapping services from representation to a corresponding Java type. For example, [jackson-jaxrs-providers](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers) implements JAX-RS `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` handlers for JSON data formats.

For more details about JAX-RS, you can have a look to [JSR-000339 JAX-RS 2.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible:

```
@Path("foo")
public class Foo {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response biz(String json) {
        return Response.ok(json).build();
    }
}
```

And your request would be like:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
             --header 'Accept: application/json' \
             -d '"Hello World"' 'http://localhost:8080/api/foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

On JAX-RS define your method as:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void example(String s) { ... }
```

On client side, send the payload without encoding to json, e.g:

```
var payload = "helloworld"; // OK
...
```

Rather than:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify("helloworld"); // KO
...
```